# Xamarin on OS X has stopped linking

Tags: macos, xamarin

Who do I now contact for support for Xamarin on mac? the support page points me here.

My project which I've had for several years has stopped compiling in the latest build.

```
Error MM2007: Xamarin.Mac Unified API against a full .NET framework does not support linking. Pass the -nolink flag. (MM2007)
```

First, I've no idea what that means. Has something changed recently? Seconds. I would change the linking options but it throws an error on saving the project options.

```
Save Failed
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Hope somebody from Xamarin is following this forum.

Comment: What did you set your linking options to under the `iOS Build` menu for the project? I also didn't find much documentation, but when [inspecting the source code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/42e5a6953e1d0f2753cf82e5152ce38276c6bb56/tools/mmp/driver.cs#L385), setting the linker behaviour to `Don't link` should solve the issue when developing against Xamarin.Mac Unified API.

Comment: It's set to Link Framework SDKs only. Do I need to rebuild this project? Changing the options throws an error. It's a big project, would be easier to change the XML of the project file to whatever the linking should be.

Comment: I don't experience the same issue myself when changing the Linker behaviour in Xamarin Studio. In any case, what you could do is first to close your project in Xamarin Studio to avoid overriding any changes you may make. Then, open the `.csproj` file for the given project in e.g. TextEdit, find the `    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>` entry for the configuration you want to change (as for instance `Debug|iPhoneSimulator`) to `None` instead of `SdkOnly`.